# SOAP Web API scan for underlying API undder my salesforce app

Tags: appexchange, security-review

we are using the web API (SOAP) as a backend in our salesforce app. Do I need to attach the ZAP/Burp or Chimera report with my submit material ? or these reports are only required for WebAppliaction . ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You should consult Salesforce Security team for more formal answers. They can be reached via scheduling an office hour as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_partner_security_portal_office_hours.htm).

Sharing from personal experience working on ISV projects

If you are using an API other than Salesforce API itself it does need to have a BURP/ZAP scan report attached. It is not be limited to just the web application.